# How to get appender file name using logger object?

Tags: perl, log4perl

I want to get appender file name using logger object.

```
my $log_conf = {
   'log4perl.rootLogger'             => "DEBUG, LOG1, SCREEN",
   'log4perl.appender.SCREEN'        => "Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen",
   'log4perl.appender.SCREEN.stderr' => "0",
   'log4perl.appender.SCREEN.layout' => "Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout",
   'log4perl.appender.SCREEN.layout.ConversionPattern' =>
     "autom:%d{yyyy_MMM_d H:m:s}_" . get_ip_address() . "_%C::: %m %n",
   'log4perl.appender.LOG1'          => "Log::Log4perl::Appender::File",
   'log4perl.appender.LOG1.filename' => file_path($file_name, $path),
   #'log4perl.appender.LOG1.mode'                        => "append",
   'log4perl.appender.LOG1.layout' => "Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout",
   'log4perl.appender.LOG1.layout.ConversionPattern' =>
     "autom:%d{yyyy_MMM_d H:m:s}_%C::: %m %n"
};
Log::Log4perl->init($log_conf);
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger($file_name);
```

I went over [doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl#Access-defined-appenders) and it says that I can access appenders using `appender_by_name()` class method.

I tried to access it using the command `$logger->appender_by_name()`, but it is returning me following error:

> Can't locate object method "appender_by_name" via package "Log::Log4perl::Logger"

```
Perl Version: 5.22
Log::Log4perl Version: 1.48
```

Following is the dump of my logger object:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'TRACE' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'DEBUG' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'FATAL' => $VAR1->{'DEBUG'},
                 'additivity' => 1,
                 'level' => undef,
                 'layout' => undef,
                 'appender_names' => [],
                 'OFF' => $VAR1->{'DEBUG'},
                 'is_WARN' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'is_TRACE' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'is_OFF' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'is_DEBUG' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'ERROR' => $VAR1->{'DEBUG'},
                 'is_INFO' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'is_ERROR' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'is_ALL' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'WARN' => $VAR1->{'DEBUG'},
                 'INFO' => $VAR1->{'DEBUG'},
                 'num_appenders' => 0,
                 'is_FATAL' => sub { "DUMMY" },
                 'category' => 'autom_controller.log',
                 'ALL' => $VAR1->{'TRACE'}
               }, 'Log::Log4perl::Logger' );
```

Answer (score 2):

`appender_by_name()` is the method in `Log::Log4perl` class. So you need to use it as:

```
Log::Log4perl->appender_by_name('LOG1')
```